# Angular 12 error as Argument of type '(response: IAppConfig)=>void' is not assignable to parameteroftype '(value:Object)=>void|PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: angular

Angular 12 error as Argument of type `(response: IAppConfig)=>void` is not assignable to parameter of type `(value:Object)=>void|PromiseLike<void>`

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IAppConfig } from './app-config.model';
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
    static settings: IAppConfig;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    load() {
        const jsonFile = 'assets/config/config.json';
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) =>
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response : IAppConfig) => {
               AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
               resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
                console.log('Configuration file could not be read');
                resolve();
            });
        });  
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your issue in https://stackblitz.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it by remove the type of response:

```
this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then(response => {
    AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
    resolve();
}
```

Please note that `toPromise` is being deprecated in RxJS 7 and will be removed in RxJS 8. So you should use `lastValueFrom` here:

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
...
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            const configSetting = this.http.get(jsonFile);
            lastValueFrom(configSetting).then((response: IAppConfig) => {
                AppConfig.settings = <IAppConfig>response;
                resolve();
            })
...
```